# Error in modifing web-context from /auth to /ddu-auth from jboss cli in openshift

Tags: jboss7.x, keycloak, openshift-origin

1. i am trying to deploy kelclock container in openshift environment
   and automatically keyclock-bootstrap.sh script will run and set
   context path to "/ddu-auth" when container start.i am struggling for
   this issue since last 4/5 days but dont find any solution
   .appriciated ,if you could help me on this issue

   if i removed bootstrap.sh file ,container will be stable ortherwise
   it restarted automatically in every 2/3 min

**Dockerfile for image creation**

```
FROM jboss/keycloak-openshift  
ADD keycloak-bootstrap.sh /usr/bin/
ADD openshift-entrypoint.sh /usr/bin/

USER root

RUN chmod +x /usr/bin/openshift-entrypoint.sh && \
    chmod +x /usr/bin/keycloak-bootstrap.sh && \
    chmod +x /opt/jboss/ddu.sh

    USER 1000

    EXPOSE 8080


**#keycloak-bootstrap.sh**

/opt/jboss/keycloak/bin/add-user-keycloak.sh -u admiin-p ert246yui 
/opt/jboss/keycloak/bin/kcadm.sh config credentials --server
http://localhost:8080/auth --realm master --user admin--password
ert246yui /opt/jboss/keycloak/bin/kcadm.sh update realms/master -s
sslRequired=NONE

sleep 50

/opt/jboss/keycloak/bin/jboss-cli.sh --connect
--command="/subsystem=keycloak-server/:write-attribute(name="web-context",value=ddu-auth)"


/opt/jboss/keycloak/bin/jboss-cli.sh --connect --command=:reload


**Error details**
######################################################### 13:09:54,018 INFO  [org.keycloak.services] (ServerService Thread
Pool -- 73) KC-SERVICES0001: Loading config from standalone.xml or
domain.xml 13:09:54,055 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Thread-2)
WFLYSRV0236: Suspending server with no timeout. 13:09:54,056 INFO 
[org.jboss.as.ejb3] (Thread-2) WFLYEJB0493: EJB subsystem suspension
complete 13:09:54,058 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Thread-2)
WFLYSRV0220: Server shutdown has been requested via an OS signal
13:09:54,062 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService
Thread Pool -- 73) MSC000001: Failed to start service
jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./ddu-auth:
org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service
jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./ddu-auth:
java.lang.RuntimeException: RESTEASY003325: Failed to construct
public
org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication(javax.servlet.ServletContext,org.jboss.resteasy.core.Dispatcher)
    at
org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:81)
    at
java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at
org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1985)
    at
org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1487)
    at
org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1378)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)    at
org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:485) Caused by:
java.lang.RuntimeException: RESTEASY003325: Failed to construct
public
org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication(javax.servlet.ServletContext,org.jboss.resteasy.core.Dispatcher)
    at
org.jboss.resteasy.core.ConstructorInjectorImpl.construct(ConstructorInjectorImpl.java:162)
    at
org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyProviderFactory.createProviderInstance(ResteasyProviderFactory.java:2676)
    at
org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment.createApplication(ResteasyDeployment.java:361)
    at
org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment.startInternal(ResteasyDeployment.java:274)
    at
org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment.start(ResteasyDeployment.java:86)
    at
org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.init(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:119)
    at
org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.init(HttpServletDispatcher.java:36)
    at
io.undertow.servlet.core.LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.proceed(LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.java:117)
    at
org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.RunAsLifecycleInterceptor.init(RunAsLifecycleInterceptor.java:78)
    at
io.undertow.servlet.core.LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.proceed(LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.java:103)
    at
io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedServlet$DefaultInstanceStrategy.start(ManagedServlet.java:300)
    at
io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedServlet.createServlet(ManagedServlet.java:140)
    at
io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$2.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:584)
    at
io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$2.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:555)
    at
io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:42)
    at
io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at
org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
```

Comment: Please edit the question to make it more readable (use the tools to frame the code / exception / error etc.)

Comment: As suggested i have made it code format